# Table-Valued Functions from Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server, functions

Why does when I try to run:

```
SELECT * FROM [servername].master.sys.dm_os_volume_stats(1, 1) AS btb (NOLOCK)
```

I get error:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 15, Line 45
'servername.master.sys.dm_os_volume_stats' is not a recognized function name.
```

And when I run it in the server (ex: servername), I get different error:

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.dm_os_volume_stats(1, 1) AS btb (NOLOCK)

Msg 317, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table-valued function 'dm_os_volume_stats' cannot have a column alias.
```

But it gets no error if I removed the `AS btb (NOLOCK)`

My goal is to query from a linked server and get free disk space for each server (using union). Below is part of the query:

```
FROM [servername].[master].sys.master_files AS f WITH(NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.file_id)
```

But Im still looking for a solution for the issue regarding TVFs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use NOLOCK hint when calling table valued function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71174/use-nolock-hint-when-calling-table-valued-function)

Comment: What SQL Server version is your linked server?

Comment: im using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a passthrough query. And get rid of NOLOCK (it doesn't even do anything here as the catalog is always read with locking read committed semantics).

EG

```
exec ('
select *
FROM [master].sys.master_files AS f 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.file_id)
') at [servername]
```

or

```
select * 
from openquery (servername, '
select database_id, file_id,  ...
FROM [master].sys.master_files AS f 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.file_id)
')
```

Comment: can I insert the result into a view? I want to call the view on sql server agent jobs

Comment: initially I manager to retrieve the result from a different server using OPEN QUERY and you answer. I also managed to by pass the error in my question. The next thing to do is if it is possible to have a repeated set of query for each server (using UNION). Thanks !

Comment: *managed.. Currently I was able to manage to insert it using DECLARE .. TABLE..